# How to improve speed of query for Firestore + Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have Flutter + Firestore app with a perfomance problem: large database query execution time (about a 5 sec.). I have a small database size, I think that if it increases, the query execution speed will be even greater. How can I improve application performance?

```
import 'package:carstat/models/entry.dart';
import 'package:carstat/models/operation.dart';
import 'package:carstat/services/data_service.dart';

class DashboardService {
  DataService dataService = DataService();

  getMarkers(List<Entry> entries, String carId) async {
    var _markers = [];

    for (int i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
      List<Operation> _operations = [];
      _operations =
          await dataService.getEntryOperations(entries[i].entryId, carId);
      _markers.add({'entry': entries[i], 'operations': _operations});

    }
    return _markers;
  }
}
```

My data structure for example:

```
        .document(docId)
        .collection('cars')
        .document(carId)
        .collection('entries')
        .document(entryId)
        .collection('operations')
        .document();
```

DataService code:

```
  getEntryOperations(String entryId, String carId) async {
    List<Operation> _operations = [];
    Future<QuerySnapshot> _userDoc =
        fs.where('userId', isEqualTo: _userId).getDocuments();
    await _userDoc.then((res) {
      docId = res.documents[0].documentID;
    });
    Future<QuerySnapshot> _entryOperations = fs
        .document(docId)
        .collection('cars')
        .document(carId)
        .collection('entries')
        .document(entryId)
        .collection('operations')
        .getDocuments();

    await _entryOperations.then((val) {
      for (int i = 0; i < val.documents.length; i++) {
        var _operation = Operation();

        _operation.entryId = entryId;
        _operation.operationNote = val.documents[i].data['operationNote'];
        _operation.operationDate =
            val.documents[i].data['operationDate'].toDate();
        _operation.operationMileage = val.documents[i].data['operationMileage'];
        _operation.operationPartName =
            val.documents[i].data['operationPartName'];
        _operation.operationPrice = val.documents[i].data['operationPrice'];
        _operation.partPrice = val.documents[i]['partPrice'];
        _operation.operationId = val.documents[i]['operationId'];
        _operations.add(_operation);
      }
    });
    return _operations;
  }
```

Comment: Your code doesn’t have a firestore query in it. Can you show the actual query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer, much faster

```
class DashboardService {
  DataService dataService = DataService();

  getMarkers(List<Entry> entries, String carId) async {
    var _marker = []; // коллекция списков операторов для каждого регламента ТО

    final opsForEntries = await Future.wait(
      entries.map((value) {
        return dataService.getEntryOperations(value.entryId, carId);
      })
    );

     for(int i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
       _marker.add(
         {
           'entry': entries[i],
           'operations': opsForEntries[i]
         }
       );
     }

    return _marker;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The query you're showing is unconditionally getting all of the documents in a specific subcollection.  Of course, that will take more time as the collection grows.  There is no secret trick or special flag to pass to make this query happen any faster.

In fact, there is not much you can do about this at all, other than to limit the size of the collection, or limit the number of documents in the query.  You might also want to reconsider your database structure to reduce the number of documents you're fetching.